# Dynamically Added Element Not showing in TD in HTML Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I have this code :

```
var closeButton = $("<a class='close'/>")
                                    .button({
                                        icons: {
                                            primary: "ui-icon-close"
                                        },
                                        text: false
                                    })
                                    .removeClass("ui-corner-all")
                                    .addClass("ui-corner-right ui-combobox-toggle")
                                    .click(function () {
                                        if (invisibleElement != null)
                                            jQuery(invisibleElement).val("");
                                        //removing the close button with placaholder value
                                        jQuery(visibleElement).val("Select");
                                        jQuery(visibleElement).focus();
                                        jQuery(visibleElement).blur();
                                        var parentNode = $(this).parent();
                                        parentNode.find(this).remove();
                                        isCloseButton = false;
                                    });
```

And I am adding this button conditionally by this:

```
$(visibleElement).parent().find(".showAll").after(closeButton);
```

This is not added by default. This is added based on some input.

These things are added within a td

```
<table border="0" width="100%" cellspacing='0' cellpadding='2'>
<tr>
    <td style="vertical-align:middle; text-align:left; width: 45%;">
                                <input type="text" id="theVisibleElement" value=""/>

    </td>
</tr>
```

But After adding the `closeButton`, I am not able to see the `showAll` element. Only the inputBox(`visibleElement`) and the `closeButton` is visible. Although, in the source code all three are there i.e visibleElement(the input TextBox), `showAll` element and `closeButton`. Strangely the `td` is enough big but still all three are not shown up. What to do? Any suggestion?

This is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8U6xq/1/
Though it's a bit messy.

Comment: Could you make a jsFiddle for this? The question is too vague, you are not showing all relevant code. Where, for instance, are the td's placed?

Comment: jsfiddle would be messed up. Ok, I'll try. But I've given all most all code.

Comment: @jtheman jsfiddle added.

Comment: I might be wrong, but your test `if (jQuery.trim($(invisibleElement).val()).length > 0 && jQuery.trim($(invisibleElement).val()) != "0") ` will always be false because it is done only once when the element is created.

Comment: @Brewal Thanks for your comment. Actually that code is never executed there. the close button is added by the code below that one and that is written in `select` event of `autocomplete`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a CSS problem. Your "close" element is right over your showAll element. See the corrected fiddle here :

http://jsfiddle.net/8U6xq/2/

I have just changed this in the css :

```
.close {
    left: 270px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But can you indicate the cause of it? As in other places, this is not being a problem and the closebutton is added normally after the Show All button.

Comment: @soham.m17 This is because of the `position: absolute;` in the `.ui-combobox-toggle` class. You could also just change it to `position: relative;`